# apply to data.frame with list column

Tags: r, apply

I would like to use apply with a data.frame that contains lists in one column. That is, one column contains vectors and I wand to perform various operations on these vectors. For example, I would like to find out how many elements there are with a certain value.

What's my mistake here?

```
#reproducible code
set.seed(1)
some_list <- replicate(40, sample(c(1:8), size=sample(3:6, 1), replace=TRUE))
exdf <- expand.grid(id=c(1:10), content=c(1:4))
exdf$dv <- some_list
exdf$edge <- replicate(40, sample(3:5, size=1))

#Prolem: get elements with lesser value than "edge" in "dv"
result <- sapply(dv~., data=exdf, function(x) which(x[, "dv"] < x[, "edge"]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Map` to do the comparison between corresponding elements in the columns

```
Map(function(x,y) which(x <y), exdf$dv, exdf$edge)
```

If we are only interested in the number of elements, use the `sum` and with `mapply` it returns a `vector`

```
mapply(function(x,y) sum(x <y), exdf$dv, exdf$edge)
```

NOTE: `Map` is just a wrapper for `mapply` which always returns a `list` output.

Or another option is `unnest` (from `tidyr`) with `dplyr` functions

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
unnest(exdf, .id = "grp") %>%
        group_by(grp) %>%
        summarise(n = sum(dv < edge))
```

Comment: Thanks! How would I pass a "na.rm=TRUE" to these functions?

Comment: @vanaoveneri  You can use `summarise(n = sum(dv < edge, na.rm=TRUE))` and in the first case `sum(x < y, na.rm = TRUE)`